# Symfony Assetic function using with variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig, templating, assetic

```
<img src="{{ asset("assets/img/sample.jpg") }}"/>
```

i want to using `sample.jpg` with filter

```
{% image "assets/img/sample.jpg" filter="jpegoptim" %}
    <img src"{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endimage %}
```

everything is all here.

but i want take file from a variable. like this:

```
{% set image = "sample.jpg" %}

{% image "assets/img/"~image filter="jpegoptim" %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endimage %}
```

Error:

```
Unexpected token "name" of value "image"
```

if i use twig jpegoptim function with this configuration

```
#config.yml

assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        jpegoptim:
            bin: /usr/bin/jpegoptim
            strip_all: true
            max: 80
    twig:
        functions:
            jpegoptim: ~
```

template file:

```
<img src="{{ jpegoptim("assets/img/"~image) }}/>
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: jpegoptim in . (which is being imported from "/var/www/html/myproject/app/cache/dev/assetic/routing.yml").
```

Comment: Try setting a variable `{% set name = "" %}`, and then using that in function.

Comment: just a guess, image is for some reason a reseverd variablename, try sth. like {% set imagename = 'xyz' %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution end of the official page here. They say use the LiipImageBundle.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/jpeg_optimize.html

Url based filter sample:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/relative/path/to/image.jpg') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```